# Finding for each array element, the left smaller elements. O(n)

Tags: arrays, numbers, complexity-theory, element

There is a famous problem which I've been looking for, which is:
On a given array, we are trying to build another array at the same size,
which each element in the new array will be the number of the smaller elements from its left in the original array (in a row). I've been searching here in StackOverflow, and I've only found solutions in O(nlogn). I think I've found a solution at O(n).

```
int[] arr = {8, 4, 3, 2, 10, 9, 7, 6, 12};
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
int[] newArr = new int[arr.length];

// Each sequence is at least 1;
for (int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    newArr[i] = 1;
}

// For each element, if it is smaller than
// the previous one, push it into the stack.
// Otherwise, compare it to all the elements
// in the stack which are smaller or equals to it,
// and summarize their values in the newArr.
stack.push(arr[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] >= arr[i-1]) {
        int j = i - 1;
        while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.top() <= arr[i]) {
            arr[i] += newArr[j];
            stack.pop();
            j--;
        }
    }
    stack.push(arr[i);
}
```

Now, the complexity time, is O(n), because any value is compared only once,
and in the worst case, where there are 'n' numbers, and they are divided into
'k' descending groups (Ex. {18, 12, 11, 9, 17, 8, 6, 4, 15, 3, 2, 1}), we're
activating the second loop only 'k' times, for 'n/k' elements. That's why
the 'k' variable does not matters and we are left with O(n) in the worst case.

*** I forgot to mention, that the newArr in the code should look like this:
{1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 9} ***

Let me know if I'm right, it's really important for me.
Sincerely,
Uriah.

Comment: This looks like O(n square)

Comment: @shikhar This is not O(n^2), because each number is added and popped from the stack exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely right with your argument. The time complexity of your code is O(n).

It can also be easily proven by the fact that each number is added and popped from the stack exactly once. Thus making it O(n).

---

Alternate algorithm to do the same task (lot more intuitive):

```
// push index instead of number itself
stack.push(0);
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    while (!stack.isEmpty() && arr[stack.top()] <= arr[i])
        stack.pop();
    if(stack.isEmpty())
        new_arr[i]=i+1;
    else
        new_arr[i]=i-stack.top()
    stack.push(i);
}
```

As you can notice, I push the index instead of number. That makes calculation of new array intuitive (just calculate difference between two indexes).